# Using param and data in $http post in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, servlets

I am sending a JSON value as my `data` in my Angular `$http` POST request. I want to add another value to the data but I am not able to add it to the JSON. So I instead thought of adding it to the `param` attribute of the POST request. But I am not able to get the value as I expected in my server side which is the Servlet.

This is my $ http post:

```
$http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'edit',
            params: oldValue,
            data: message,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).then(function(response) {
            console.log("Response in service" + response.data);
            message.value = oldValue;
            return response.data;
        })
```

This is my Servlet:

```
String objectName = "";
objectName = request.getQueryString();
System.out.println("object name == "+ objectName);
```

I can actually get part of the data. But I am not able to get the whole data.

Any suggestions on alternate ways to accomplish this are welcome.

Comment: I think its not possible to pass params in POST request, params means pass value in url parameter, which is for GET request.

Comment: can I do this using servlet params ?? can I add the value I want as a param in my url attribute in $http ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass additional data in data field only as you api method's parameter.

```
$http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'edit',
        data: { parameter1 : mssage, parameter2 : oldValue } 
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }).then(function(response) {
        console.log("Response in service" + response.data);
        message.value = oldValue;
        return response.data;
    })
```

Comment: Right now I can get the values in the data attribute bgy using getReader method on request. But if I pass two variables in the data, how can I get the values in the servlet ?